# Target Only Safari in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I've got this code running on my squarespace site very nicely, which utilises a video as a background image. Only problem is I've created a custom navigation menu, and added some jquery elsewhere, which seems to stop working in Safari whenever the video is set as the background banner image.

I tried adding Safari to the list of useragents but naturally that affected chrome as well, and the video would not play.

Can anyone tell me how to target the safari desktop browser to ignore the script without it affecting Chrome as well?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).bind("load", function() {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
    {
      } else {
      var banner = $('#pageWrapper img').first();
      if (banner.length === 0)
        banner = $('.banner-thumbnail-wrapper > #thumbnail > img').first();
      if (banner.length === 0)
        banner = $('#parallax-images img').first();
      if (banner.length === 0)
        banner = $('.has-main-image img').first();
      if (banner.length === 0)
          banner = $('.primary-image img').first();
     if (banner.length === 0)
          banner = $('#page-thumb img').first();
      var url = "https://max-fedorov-pzor.squarespace.com/s/Frog-eggs.mp4";
      banner.hide();
      $('<video class="bannerVideo" autoplay="" loop="" preload><source src="' + url + '" type="video/mp4"></video>').insertAfter(banner);
      adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
      setTimeout(function() {
        adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
      }, 2000);
      $(window, banner).resize(function() {
        adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
        setTimeout(function() {
          adjustBanner($('.bannerVideo'), banner);
        }, 200);
      });
    }
    function adjustBanner (video, banner) {
      video.css({
        height: banner.css('height'),
        width: banner.css('width'),
        top: banner.css('top'),
        left: banner.css('left'),
        position: 'relative',
        'object-fit': 'inherit'
      });
    }
  });
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack to check for safari. I haven't tested it, but supposedly it works for detecting all versions of safari.

```
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);
```

There are some more options; There are some that are specific for <=v5 or v6. I found them on http://browserhacks.com/ searching for 'safari'

There's also an object that should ideally only be defined in chrome `window.chrome` so you could check if it's undefined to eliminate chrome.

Another option -- may not be relevant in this case, but if you know the exact feature you need to use, and you don't mind using a library: https://modernizr.com/